Adapt exception type of generic throwing iterator
I have an interface ThrowingIterator, which follows the general contract of Iterator, except the hasNext() and next() methods can throw exceptions:
public interface ThrowingIterator<T, E extends Throwable> {
  boolean hasNext() throws E;
  T next() throws E;
  default void remove() throws E { /* throw unsupported */ }
  // forEachRemaining same as Iterator
}

I can change the return type of the iterator by using an adapt function, similar to how Stream has map(Function<? super T, U> mapper). However, I haven't been able to figure out a way to change the exception type of the iterator, like the following:
// example method
default <X extends Throwable> ThrowingIterator<T, X> adaptException(Function<? super E, ? extends X> exceptionMapper) {
  return new ThrowingIterator<T, X> {
    public boolean hasNext() {
      try {
        return this.hasNext();
      } catch (E e) { // this does not work, can't catch E
        throw exceptionMapper.apply(e);
      }
    }
  }
  // same for next()
}

// example use
ThrowingIterator<Integer, IOException> baseIterator = getIterator();
ThrowingIterator<Integer, ExecutionException> adaptedIterator = baseIterator.adaptException(ExecutionException::new);

My main difficulty in writing this function comes from the fact that Java does not allow a generic exception type to be caught. Is there any way around this restriction? I could catch all Throwables and check if they're of the expected type using a class object, but that feels clunky.

As I understand it, generics were added for extended static time type checking. Can you explain (because I don't understand) why this couldn't just be throws Throwable if you want to use existing Exception classes, or throws IterableThrowable if you want these exceptions to stem from a new base class? What do you gain by using generics?

@ControlAltDel An iterator being able to throw a generic exception allows checked exceptions from its data source to be thrown upwards naturally. If an iterator throws Throwable, the caller of iter.hasNext() would need to catch all throwables, and determine manually which one they need to care about. throws IterableThrowable as a means of wrapping exceptions leads to repeated boilerplate of iterThrowable.getCause().

@ControlAltDel my use case was to provide a stream of elements sourced from a paginated REST API, so I wanted to 1. avoid grabbing all of the elements at once and 2. communicate to the caller that IOExceptions may occur in the middle of the data stream.

"An iterator being able to throw a generic exception allows checked exceptions from its data source to be thrown upwards naturally." < No, generics don't work this way in Java. Using throws Throwable as a base you can do it by specifying a subclass that extends Throwable in a specific ThrowingIterator

@ControlAltDel Is that not what I'm doing when I make a class ExternalSourceIterator extends ThrowingIterator<DataObject, IOException>? If the signature was instead interface ThrowingIterator<T> then there's no way to communicate the exception type of the iterator from a method that returns a ThrowingIterator<DataObject>. The caller would have to either catch Throwable or mark their method as throws Throwable, which from my understanding is bad practice.

I found a solution that satisfied what I wanted:
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T, E extends Exception, X extends Throwable> ThrowingIterator<T, X> adaptException(ThrowingIterator<T, E> iter, Class<E> exceptionType, Function<? super E, ? extends X> exceptionMappingFunction) {
  if (NoSuchElementException.class.isAssignableFrom(exceptionType) 
      || RuntimeException.class.equals(exceptionType) 
      || Exception.class.equals(exceptionType)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Applying this method to an iterator that is typed to throw a superclass of NoSuchElementException is a Very Bad Idea. " 
        + "The returned iterator would have no way to communicate if such an exception thrown was because the source iterator ran out of elements, or because " 
        + "the data source threw an exception. This method should only be used on iterators that throw checked exceptions, as a way to add additional " 
        + "context to an exception that came from the iterator's data source, although other unchecked exceptions are permissible");
  }
  return new ThrowingIterator<T, X>() {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() throws X {
      try {
        return iter.hasNext();
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // Unchecked cast warning suppressed since we check if it's an instance of E
        if (exceptionType.isInstance(e)) throw exceptionMappingFunction.apply((E) e);
        // allows NoSuchElementException to pass through normally
        throw e;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // Should never have a ClassCastException since the iterator can only throw E or a RuntimeException subclass
        throw exceptionMappingFunction.apply((E) e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public T next() throws X {
      try {
        return iter.next();
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (exceptionType.isInstance(e)) throw exceptionMappingFunction.apply((E) e);
        throw e;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw exceptionMappingFunction.apply((E) e);
      }
    }
  };
}

The big IllegalArgumentException check at the top is necessary because there's no way for me to wildcard <E extends Exception && !(E super NoSuchElementException)>, since I want all NoSuchElementExceptions to continue to be thrown upward without having the mapping function applied. I also didn't use <E extends Throwable> because I especially didn't want to interrupt an Error being thrown up the call stack.


I could catch all Throwables and check if they're of the expected type using a class object, but that feels clunky.

I'm sorry it feels clunky to you, but it's your only option.

Here's how I would do this (this is based on my work on DataFetcher (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java) from years ago)
public interface ThrowingIterator<T,E> extends Iterator<T> {
  // because this extends Iterator, the client must implement those methods as well
  void exceptionOccurred(E e);
}

Now the client has a specific method to implement to handle the case where there is an error during the iteration.

I like that it provides implementors a way to handle exceptions, but I need a way to communicate to the caller of iter.hasNext() that they should handle the case where an IOException prevented the iterator from determining if there is a next element. The Iterator interface doesn't allow for throwing exceptions, which would likely result in the caller getting surprised by an IOException wrapped in an unchecked exception if such a case occurred and the iterator couldn't handle it internally

If your goal is to simplify construction and usage, then the following method might be more practical:
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
default ThrowingIterator<T, RuntimeException> adaptException() {
    return (ThrowingIterator<T, RuntimeException>) this;
}

This way, the caller can clearly see what exceptions may be thrown through the generic parameters. If the caller wants to handle exceptions, they can use try-catch directly; if they prefer not to handle them, they can just call adaptException() before invoking the method. Here’s an example:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThrowingIterator<String, IOException> throwingIterator = new ThrowingIterator<>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        @Override
        public String next() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    };
    // 1. if the caller wants to handle the exception
    try {
        throwingIterator.hasNext();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something
    }
    // 2. or the caller can propagate the exception
    throwingIterator.adaptException().hasNext();
}

